# executing a SELECT query and check if any row is returned and if empty resultset do an INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

been following this php/mysql tutorial i found online and now i can't get this query to work. The issue i believe is with using the insert query after null resultset is returned from the select query.

```
$new_start_no = isset($_POST['start_no']) ? $_POST['start_no'] : '';
$new_end_no = isset($_POST['end_no']) ? $_POST['end_no'] : '';
$new_job_no = isset($_POST['job_no']) ? $_POST['job_no'] : '';

$query = "SELECT COUNT (*)"; 
$query .= "FROM jobs";
$query .= "WHERE job_no=$new_job_no"; 
$query .= "AND start_no <= $new_end_no";
$query .= "AND end_no >= $new_start_no";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if (is_null) { 
$query = "INSERT INTO jobs (";
 $query .= " user_id, start_no, end_no, start_date, client_name, card_type, job_no, job_quantity, end_date, shred_option";
 $query .= ") VALUES (";
 $query .= " '{$user_id}', '{$start_no}', '{$end_no}', '{$start_date}', '{$client_name}', '{$card_type}', '{$job_no}', '{$job_quantity}', '{$end_date}', '{$shred_option}'";
 $query .= ")";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 if ($result) {
// success
   $_SESSION["message"] = "job created.";
   redirect_to("manage_job.php"); 
  } else {
// failure  
   $_SESSION["message"] = "job creation failed.";
   redirect_to("new_job.php");
  }  
}
```

Comment: You should [bind your variable data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) especially since it's being passed in via a web request.

Comment: `if (is_null)` - is_null is not a variable

Answer (score 1):

Your query always returns exactly 1 row, since it uses `COUNT(*)` to count the matching rows. You need to retrieve the row and get the count from it. You should assign an alias to the count so you can retrieve it. Then you need to test the count, not `is_null`.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT (*) AS ct"; 
$query .= "FROM jobs";
$query .= "WHERE job_no=$new_job_no"; 
$query .= "AND start_no <= $new_end_no";
$query .= "AND end_no >= $new_start_no";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_rows = $row['ct'];
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    // INSERT code
} else {
    $_session["message"] = "job no is not available";
}
```

Comment: the query works perfectly now without throwing up errors but unfortunately it did not achieve the required task which is to flag a message "job creation failed" when resultset displays rows is in the table "jobs"

Comment: See my updated answer. "job creation failed" only happens when there's a database error when you try to do the insert.